# Get names of printers on printserver

Tags: c#, printing, server, names

we have a print server and lots of printers on it. We access them like this:

```
\\print-server-name\printer1
\\print-server-name\printer1_color
\\print-server-name\printer2
```

...etc.

I now need a list of all printers on that server. Until now, I could only find all printers installed locally on the machine. I found this while googling which gave me only the local printers aswell:

```
PrintServer lps = new PrintServer();
PrintQueueCollection prQueue = lps.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });
liServerPrinterNames = (from printer in prQueue select printer).ToList();
```

Actually I only need the names of all printers on the server in a string array, I don't even need objects for interaction, only the names of all printers as string. Is that possible? How?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Look at the constructors; `new PrintServer(@"\\print-server-name");`

Comment: Hello Alex. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this solution only returned the local printers aswell.

Comment: I found another website with an example here: [link](http://www.encodedna.com/2013/04/show-printers-using-wmi.htm)

But even the example over there including this loop:
`if (Convert.ToBoolean(Printers["Network"]))     // ALL NETWORK PRINTERS.
        {
            cmbNetworkPrinters.Items.Add(Printers["Name"]);
        }`
...gave me only the local printers. Could this be some sort of policy restriction?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it:

```
using System.Printing;

string serverAddress = @"\\server.domain.local"
PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer($@"{serverAddress}")
PrintQueueCollection queues = printServer.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local });
foreach (var item in queues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name)
}
```

If you want the full name (\\server.domain.local\PrinterName) use property FullName instead of Name :)

Answer (score 0):

Gets all InstalledPrinters

```
  foreach (string printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
```

Using WMI Windows Management Instrumentation

```
 SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
    ManagementObjectSearcher mos= new ManagementObjectSearcher(mos, query);
    System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc= mos.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject Printers in moc )
        Printers["Name"];               //GetPrinterName
}
```

Comment: Hello Hüseyin. Thanks for your suggestion.
First of all:
`new ManagementObjectSearcher(mos, query);`
returned "cannot convert from System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher to string" so I replaced "mos" with "null" at first.
Then this piece of code also returned me only the installed printers on the local machine.